# Turning on Word Wrap for the Eclipse XQuery Plugin

Tags: eclipse, xquery

How Can I Turn on Word Wrap for the Eclipse XQuery Plugin?

It does not seem to be in the window preferences section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We Are currently working also on the code formatter. Therefore wrapping is not currently supported in the XQDT editor. I also don't see a workaround for it either. But I took a note about this. Follow us on twitter @XQDT too see when we come up with something new. The formatter will also com but not in the very near future.

Answer (score 0):

It is in the Window Preferences section even without the plugin. Try going to

Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter

create a new eclipse profile then set the maximum line width to whatever you want under the 'line wrapping' tab. apply the feature and click 'Ok'.